# How to mount Sharepoint online (Office 365) on Ubuntu as davfs2

Tags: sharepoint-online

This is what I have tried:

```
sudo mount -t davfs https://myorg.sharepoint.com/ /sharepoint
[sudo] password for user: 
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
https://myorg.sharepoint.com/ or hit enter for none.
  Username: username
Please enter the password to authenticate user username with server
https://myorg.sharepoint.com/ or hit enter for none.
  Password:  
/sbin/mount.davfs: Mounting failed.
403 FORBIDDEN
```

I can access the site with the same user on the web, which confirms the Authenticity.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/851483/mount-sharepoint-online-office-365-in-linux